# How to create the = and + key with kbd tag?

Tags: html, css, tags

<kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>+=</kbd> can't create the following key.

[[image: to put + at the top of = [1]]

How to create a key gui which chracter `+` is at the top of  character `=` with `kbd` tag or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to give this a try using a pure-CSS solution.

So here's the HTML, only tweaked with a `plus-equals` classname so that we can single it out with a CSS selector, and then a bunch of CSS styles to make it look like a two-line plus/equals key:

```css
kbd.plus-equals {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #FFF;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 1px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px #999;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  overflow: visible;
}

kbd.plus-equals:after {
  content: "+\0a=";
  color: #666;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 12px;
  width: 16px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 6px;
}
```

```html
Please type the <kbd class='plus-equals'>+=</kbd> key.
```

How does this work?  By totally cheating!

The first set of CSS declarations hide the original "+=" content by shrinking it down to almost nothing, and then rendering it as white on a white background.  They also add a nice border and box shadow so that it looks like a keyboard key.

The second set of CSS declarations inject replacement content after the original content:  The replacement content has "+" and "=" on separate lines, and is carefully formatted to line up over top of the original key-shaped rectangle.

It's a hacky, cool way to make proper, clean, semantic HTML markup into something that looks like the desired result, without needing any JavaScript to clean it up after the fact.

Answer (score 2):

### In Plain HTML

Use the `<br />` tag to break the signs as follows

### The markup

```
<kbd>+<br/>=</kbd>
```

### The output

<kbd>+
=</kbd>

### The code

```html
<kbd>+<br />=</kbd>
```

### In JavaScript

#### How to do this

> Get the innerHTML of `kbd` tag, use JavaScript `split` function with `""`, then it will split each character and make an array.
>   Then Join the array with `<br />` and then add it as the `innerHTML` of the same `kbd` tag

#### References

1. [String.prototype.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
2. [Array.prototype.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)
3. [element.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

#### Code

```js
var kbd=document.getElementsByTagName("kbd")[0];
kbd.innerHTML=kbd.innerHTML.split("").join("<br />");
```

```html
<kbd>+=</kbd>
```

> In JavaScript, it is recommended to put the JavaScript just above the closing `</body>` tag. Then only it can find the corresponding element.

That is

```html
<body>
  <kbd>+=</kbd>
  <script>
      var kbd=document.getElementsByTagName("kbd")[0];
      kbd.innerHTML=kbd.innerHTML.split("").join("<br />");
  </script>
</body>
```

### In JavaScript, based on Events

Try clicking on the button and the `<kbd>` will change.

```js
function change(index){
  var kbd=document.getElementsByTagName("kbd")[0];
  kbd.innerHTML=kbd.innerHTML.split("").join("<br />");
}
```

```html
<kbd>+=</kbd>
<br />
<button onclick="change();">Change(0)</button>
```

### JavaScript Solution if you want to change multiple items.

Try clicking on the button and the corresponding `<kbd>` will be changed.

```js
function change(index){
  var kbd=document.getElementsByTagName("kbd")[index];
  kbd.innerHTML=kbd.innerHTML.split("").join("<br />");
}
```

```html
<kbd>+=</kbd>
<br />
<button onclick="change(0);">Change(0)</button>
<br />
<kbd>+=</kbd>
<br />
<button onclick="change(1);">Change(1)</button>
<br />
<kbd>+=</kbd>
<br />
<button onclick="change(2);">Change(2)</button>
<br />
<kbd>+=</kbd>
<br />
<button onclick="change(3);">Change(3)</button>
```